# Possible to speed this java code up?

Tags: java, optimization

I have some code in an Android app that when I profile my app it is the thing that takes up most of the time. I have tried to optimize it but still is taking up most of CPU time. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can speed this up.  This is a condensed version of the code Im using:

Inputs:
d is array floats
a is array floats
e is array floats

Output:
out is an array of 3 floats

Code:

```
float [] c=new float[3];
float [] b=new float[3];
float [] out=new float[3];

c[0] = a[0] - d[0 * 4 + 3];
c[1] = a[1] - d[1 * 4 + 3];
c[2] = a[2] - d[2 * 4 + 3];

b[0] = c[0]*d[0 * 4 + 0] + c[1]*d[1 * 4 + 0] + c[2]*d[2 * 4 + 0];
b[1] = c[0]*d[0 * 4 + 1] + c[1]*d[1 * 4 + 1] + c[2]*d[2 * 4 + 1];
b[2] = c[0]*d[0 * 4 + 2] + c[1]*d[1 * 4 + 2] + c[2]*d[2 * 4 + 2];           

out[0] = b[0] * e[0 * 4 + 0] + b[1] * e[0 * 4 + 1] + b[2] * e[0 * 4 + 2] + e[0 * 4 + 3];
out[1] = b[0] * e[1 * 4 + 0] + b[1] * e[1 * 4 + 1] + b[2] * e[1 * 4 + 2] + e[1 * 4 + 3];
out[2] = b[0] * e[2 * 4 + 0] + b[1] * e[2 * 4 + 1] + b[2] * e[2 * 4 + 2] + e[2 * 4 + 3];
```

For those interested in what its for its vertex transformation of a 3D model animation. 'out' is the transformed vertex, 'a' original vertex. The rest of the arrays are skeleton joint information.

Comment: I would consider actually using explicitly named local variables instead of arrays like this.

Comment: It is possible (and many would say, necessary) to make it much more concise. Speed could possibly be improved by a hair. If this is taking all the CPU time, that would be because it's being executed millions of times every second, not because it is slow.

Comment: You might start by explaining what the hell this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Your code is going to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the assignment to `c[0]` (3 is not a legal subscript for array `d` of length 3). You can't get much faster than that. :) (I second the suggestion by @Code-Guru.)

Comment: If `d` and `e` are arrays of 3 floats, then how come you are accessing indexes of up to 11? e.g. `d[2 * 4 + 3]]`

Comment: I second @LouisWasserman; unless this is to be made more generic in the future, only `d` and `e` appear to be of "some larger length" (although the code and statements in the post disagree!) and thus `b`,`c`, and `out` can be "unrolled". If this were a space transformation the "sub-variables" might be `x`, `y`, `z` and if this was dealing with colors, perhaps `r`, `g`, `b`. This *might* allow skipping some run-time array-bounds checks, and I would argue "cleaner" code, although I make no claims to if it would "increase performance".

Comment: Guys, `d[]` and `e[]` are nowhere described as being arrays of 3 floats.

Comment: @EJP The original question said they were arrays of 3 floats, it was edited 8 hours ago (3 hours after DNA's comment).

Answer (score 1):

What does the rest of the code do? This looks like a tiny piece of code, so it should execute extremely fast. Do you really have a performance problem, or are you trying to make your program consume no CPU at all?

That said, you could simly pre-compute all those trivial arithmetic operations:

```
c[0] = a[0] - d[3];
c[1] = a[1] - d[7];
c[2] = a[2] - d[11];
```

etc.

I don't understand how you can access `d[3]`, `d[7]` and `d[11]` though, since `d` is supposed to be an array of 3 elements.

Comment: +1 For asking what the rest of the code does. A decent compiler should optimize all the arithmetic with constants anyway.

Comment: I've modified the question so it explains what the code is for. Its for vertex transformation in 3D animation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do with this.. all of the operations are assignment and mathematical and you don't implement those.  In addition, those operations are already extremely fast... It would be more memory efficient to do this in a for loop of some sort since java has to store all of those numbers before multiplying. It would be more efficient to do dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I cant see any way to speed it up. I thought maybe there was something I missed where it could come out to some simple equation but I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one multiplication by zero can be simplified to zero and then remove the addition but I am confident that their the compiler or hotspot will already do that.

You could try [memoising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoisation) the results to prevent recomputation.

Also, you could try using [JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/) to offload this kind of math to the GPU, though I don't know if this is supported on Android.

Comment: (a side note) HotSpot won't help you much on Android, but compile-time constants aren't its job anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All the compile-time constants will (*must*) be constant-folded by the compiler. All you can do is eliminate the temporary arrays, which you aren't using as arrays anyway. I tried it like this:

```
public float[]  transform2(float[] a, float[] d, float[] e)
{
    float c0,c1,c2;
    float b0,b1,b2;
    float [] out=new float[3];

    c0 = a[0] - d[0 * 4 + 3];
    c1 = a[1] - d[1 * 4 + 3];
    c2 = a[2] - d[2 * 4 + 3];

    b0 = c0*d[0 * 4 + 0] + c1*d[1 * 4 + 0] + c2*d[2 * 4 + 0];
    b1 = c0*d[0 * 4 + 1] + c1*d[1 * 4 + 1] + c2*d[2 * 4 + 1];
    b2 = c0*d[0 * 4 + 2] + c1*d[1 * 4 + 2] + c2*d[2 * 4 + 2];           

    out[0] = b0 * e[0 * 4 + 0] + b1 * e[0 * 4 + 1] + b2 * e[0 * 4 + 2] + e[0 * 4 + 3];
    out[1] = b0 * e[1 * 4 + 0] + b1 * e[1 * 4 + 1] + b2 * e[1 * 4 + 2] + e[1 * 4 + 3];
    out[2] = b0 * e[2 * 4 + 0] + b1 * e[2 * 4 + 1] + b2 * e[2 * 4 + 2] + e[2 * 4 + 3];

    return out;
}
```

Your code took 35665ms to run `10000000000L` iterations. `transform2()` took 20077ms so it is a bit under twice as fast. Both methods were warmed up first, and a[], d[], and e[] contained random floats.

I wondered if it might be possible to improve things by making `out` a parameter instead of allocating it inside the method, if `out` can be conserved externally, but that may not be possible in your calling code. However adding it as a fourth parameter made it an order of magnitude worse: it must have undone some HotSpot optimization. But as you're on Android you might consider this if it's feasible.

That's a lot of iterations ...

Comment: Thanks. I tried turning c and b into variables like in your example but when I profiled my app it didnt improve that much.